# Getting Error while Reading Excel Using Spring-batch-excel

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring-batch-excel for reading a excel file in my new application. It is configured as a batch job and triggered using JobManager. Now i getting this error.
**InputStream MUST either support mark/reset, or be wrapped as a PushbackInputStream**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: InputStream MUST either support mark/reset, or be wrapped as a PushbackInputStream
at org.springframework.batch.item.excel.poi.PoiItemReader.openExcelFile(PoiItemReader.java:82) ~[spring-batch-excel-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.springframework.batch.item.excel.AbstractExcelItemReader.doOpen(AbstractExcelItemReader.java:111) ~[spring-batch-excel-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE].
```

Any please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at `spring-batch-excel` sources :

```
@Override
protected void openExcelFile(final Resource resource) throws Exception {
    workbookStream = resource.getInputStream();
    if (!workbookStream.markSupported() && !(workbookStream instanceof PushbackInputStream)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("InputStream MUST either support mark/reset, or be wrapped as a PushbackInputStream");
    }

    [...]
}
```

This exception is thrown if the `InputStream` does not support back reading. The `InputStream` depends of your `Resource`, so my conclusion would be that your resource is not a valid XLS/XLSX file.

Answer (score 8):

Old question and I'm sure you figured it out, but I find the current answer to be unhelpful,sooo...

The `Resource` you're using could be an issue. Most `spring-batch-excel` examples utilize `ClassPathResource`. When you try to productionalize your code, you'll likely need to reach for files outside of your classpath. The obvious choice is `FileSystemResource`, but that will result in this Exception.  Instead, look at `UrlResource`.

Comment: public PoiItemReader excelReader() {
    PoiItemReader reader = new PoiItemReader();
    reader.setResource(new UrlResource("file:///path/to/your/excel/file"));
    reader.setRowMapper(rowMapper());
    return reader;
}

Answer (score 4):

As @Thrax mentioned, *spring-batch-excel* expect to find a `PushbackInputStream` within the `Resource`. Here my solution to this problem when working with file on the filesystem:

I create my reader using input file from command line `--input.file`

```
@Bean
public PoiItemReader excelReader(@Value("${input.file}") String inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PoiItemReader reader = new PoiItemReader();
    PushbackInputStream input = new PushbackInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(input);
    reader.setResource(resource);
    reader.setRowMapper(rowMapper());
    return reader;
}
```

I hope it may helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue , but i faced this issue, yet for those who have the same issue like me, i commented out this code of block and it worked

```
if (!workbookStream.markSupported() && !(workbookStream instanceof PushbackInputStream)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("InputStream MUST either support mark/reset, or be wrapped as a PushbackInputStream");
    }
```

to understand why please refer to this code : 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/issues/34

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue today. The solution was to load the file from disk and not from the classpath. The interesting part is that on our local Windows environments loading from classpath worked fine, but not on a Unix environment. I suspect there might be some corruption going on in the excel file when packaged ina JAR. At any rate, we specify in a URL query parameter the location of the excel file to load, prefixed with `classpath:` to load it from the Java CLASSPATH, or `file:` to load it from disk. So all we had to do was put the file in some path on the same server as the running app, then update the URL query parameter to its location like this:

http://some.host.com?location=file:/absolute/path/to/excel/file

and voila. Internally we use Spring's [ResourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html), which is nothing more than the Spring `ApplicationContext`. The [ResourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) understands `classpath:` and `file:` prefixes and interprets each accordingly (read the documentation on the [ResourceLoader.getResource()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) method for more details). We got a reference to the Spring's [ResourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) simply by having our `@Service` component implement Spring's `ResourceLoaderAware`.